# Python img : wrong x and y position

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I use Phyton, include opencv and numpy.

i'm new in this world.

I just wanna write mid point, and on other code wanna re use from this point, but why after i use, it's change value between x and y..

```
midX = int(np.mean(MatrixX))
midY = int(np.mean(MatrixY))
#minY = np.min(MatrixY)

img[midX,midY] = [0,0,0]
#img[midX,minY] = [0,0,255]

print "here the problem :", midX,midY
```

and this for more clear problem..
[image]

I'm strongly believe midX must be 307 and midY is 229.
and i use it in set black color with [0,0,0] but after i set color black, the value x and y is changed("here the problem"), idk if i missing something here,,

Comment: `img[midX,midY] = [0,0,0]` should be `img[midY,midX] = [0,0,0]`. You access a matrix by `(row, col)`, which corresponds to `(y,x)`

Comment: so the command for img is img[y,x] ?

Comment: put in answer,,,
that is answer everything.. lol..

Comment: Already close as duplicate of a question with an answer that explains this very well

Comment: i didn't delete this, just if someone wrong keyword, they know where they must go.. thanks mike.. :)